# Count and summarise ID's each day while creating a new column that shows the accumulated ID's

Tags: r

I have two column, first one being the ID of a customer and second one being the Date of purchase.

```
    ID       Date
     1 2017-01-17
     2 2017-01-17
     3 2017-01-17
     4 2017-01-17
     5 2017-01-17
     1 2017-01-17
     7 2017-01-17
     1 2017-01-17
     9 2017-01-18
     2 2017-01-18
     3 2017-01-18
     5 2017-01-18
     1 2017-01-18
     2 2017-01-18
```

I would like to summarise the `Purchases` made by a `Customer` at one day and create a third column that shows the `amount of purchases` for the customer on that date.

Answer (score 1):

This is a base solution for your problem:

```
aggregate(paste(ID , Date) ~ ID + Date, data = df, FUN = length)
```

there are many more solutions like any of the ones below, using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(ID, Date) %>% summarise(PurchaseCount = n())
df %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>% tally(name="PurchaseCount")
df %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>% count(name="PurchaseCount")
df %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>% add_tally(name="PurchaseCount")
df %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>% add_count(name="PurchaseCount")
```

or by using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, PurchaseCount:=.N, by = list(ID, Date)]
```

or using [sqldf](/questions/tagged/sqldf) package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT ID, Date, COUNT(*) as PurchaseCount
       FROM df
       GROUP BY Date, ID")
```

or [plyr](/questions/tagged/plyr):

```
plyr::count(df, c('ID','Date'))
```

I personally prefer `data.table` as it is directly writes to the dataframe and often is time efficient. `aggregate` is also favorable when you wanna avoid loading new libraries. `dplyr` generally make your code more legible as it uses piping<sup>personal opinion</sup>.